# no visible @interface for NSMutableString declares the selector 'subStringWithRange' error

Tags: objective-c, string, nsmutablestring

I want first three characters from the below string.
My code as follows.

```
NSMutableString *str = @"test123";
NSMutableString *strTest = [str subStringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,2)];
```

But I am getting this error

> no visible @interface for NSMutableString declares the selector subStringWithRange error

Advance thanks for proper solution.

Comment: Look at the docs for the method's actual name. Hint: case matters.

Comment: Suggestion - Make use of Xcode's code completion feature. It will help avoid little mistakes like this.

Comment: NSMutableString *strTest = [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,2)];

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo. 

Comment: Btw. Your first line should already give a compiler error ( a string literal is not mutable).

Comment: Thanks Eugene Prokoshev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NSString` instead:

```
NSMutableString *str = @"test123" ;
NSString *strTest = [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,2)];
```

Comment: Nope.  The method is also on NSMutableString.

Comment: No compilation error with NSString

Comment: Why are you using `stringWithFormat:` on the 1st line? Totally pointless.

Comment: My fault was subStringWithRange(S in uppercase). if i make it smaller it is working for both NSString and NSMutableString. Anyways thanks for your quick answer.